# How to Add Role to Someone who Passes a Test on Discord PY

Tags: python, discord

How would you add a role to someone using discord py within a bot.event, async def on_message(message)? This is my code so far, and my attempted code:              **message.author.add_roles("Test ROle")**

```
`@bot.event
async def on_message(message):

if 'verification' not in message.channel.name:
      return

   elif message.attachments:
      attachment = content=message.attachments[0].url
      confID = random.randint(100000000, 999999999)

      getImage(attachment, confID) #Just an outside function to get the image
      await message.delete()
#Run the OCR Algorithm
      if ocrVerify(str(confID) + '.png') == True:
             **message.author.add_roles("Test ROle")**
      else:          print("DM A MOD")`
```

Answer (score 0):

That's indeed how you should proceed. Use the role ID, though.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):

if 'verification' not in message.channel.name:
      return

   elif message.attachments:
      attachment = content=message.attachments[0].url
      confID = random.randint(100000000, 999999999)

      getImage(attachment, confID) #Just an outside function to get the image
      await message.delete()
#Run the OCR Algorithm
      if ocrVerify(str(confID) + '.png') == True:
             message.author.add_roles("ID of the role to add")
      else:          print("DM A MOD")`
```

Also make sure that the bot has the right permissions and is above the role to be able to add it to your members.

Comment: After fixing the role assignment, I'm still given errors. 
Error: